# How to make the middle text box shrink so that only the slider and the image is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to make it shrink, CSS:

```css
.infocard {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: auto !important;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.cardcontent {
  display: flex;
}

.cardimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
.cardslider {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  width: 7%;
  background-color: #5E6282;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.anglebracket {
 position: absolute;
 transition: all;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.anglebracket:active{
  position: absolute;
}

.imgholder {
  margin-top: 6.5rem;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.clickables {
  display: none;
}

.clickables + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.clickables:checked + label .imgholder img {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.cardtext {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x, 1rem);
  padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x, 1rem);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
 .col-lg-3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
}
.fs-xl-10 {
  font-size: 3.24732rem !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="mb-4 text-start">
      <h5 class="text-secondary">It's not hard to become a better friend to the environment</h5>
      <h3 class="fs-xl-10 fs-lg-8 fs-7 fw-bold font-cursive text-capitalize mg ">How to be a more <span class="greengrad">Eco-Friendly</span> Person</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="infocard">
      <div class="cardcontent">
        <div class="cardslider">
          <input type="checkbox" class="clickables" id="checkbox" onclick="opencs()">
          <label for="checkbox" class="clickables">
            <div class="imgholder"><img src="assets/img/down-arrow.png" width="25px" class="anglebracket angleflip" id="angleb"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="textwrap">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h3 class="sectext" style="margin-bottom: 4%;">Get <span class="fw-bold">Electric</span>  or <span class="fw-bold">Fuel-Efficient</span> vehicles </h3>
                <p class="sectext">While an Electric vehicle is the best option of the two, getting a vehicle that consumes less gasoline is also a decent option.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cardimage"><img src="assets/img/car.jpg" style="border-top-right-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;" height="300" width="400"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried making the middle box (card-text div) shrink upon clicking the cardslider so that the box is invisible and the image and slider are next to each other visible I tried with **display:grid**  and **display:flex**, but maybe I am doing something wrong. I also wanted to add a 1sec transition to it but if I can't get it to shrink then what's the point in adding it?

Comment: Please include your Javascript code that handles clicking the card slider.

Comment: there is no javascript code, its all based in css

Comment: the onclick="opencs()" isnt a function yet, i thought about doing something but didnt do it

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .infocard {
            display: grid;
            border-radius: 15px;
            max-width: 80%;
            width: auto !important;
            max-height: 300px;
            background: white;
        }
        .cardcontent {
            display: flex;
        }
        .cardimage {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
            border-top-right-radius: 15px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .cardslider {
            border-top-left-radius: 15px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
            width: 7%;
            background-color: #5E6282;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .anglebracket {
            position: absolute;
            transition: all;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;
        }
        .anglebracket:active{
            position: absolute;
        }
        .imgholder {
            margin-top: 6.5rem;
            height: 50px;
            width: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .clickables {
            display: none;
        }
        .clickables + label {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        .clickables:checked + label .imgholder img {
            transition: transform 1s;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        .cardtext {
            padding-left: 5%;
            padding-top: 5%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .text-wrap {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x, 1rem);
            padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x, 1rem);
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        .col-lg-3 {
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            width: 40%;
        }
        .fs-xl-10 {
            font-size: 3.24732rem !important;
        }
        .textwrap.remove {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-4 text-start">
            <h5 class="text-secondary">It's not hard to become a better friend to the environment</h5>
            <h3 class="fs-xl-10 fs-lg-8 fs-7 fw-bold font-cursive text-capitalize mg ">How to be a more <span class="greengrad">Eco-Friendly</span> Person</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="infocard">
            <div class="cardcontent">
                <div class="cardslider" onclick="opencs()">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="clickables" id="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox" class="clickables">
                        <div class="imgholder">
                            <img src="assets/img/down-arrow.png" width="25px" class="anglebracket angleflip" id="angleb">
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="textwrap" id="textwrap">
                    <div class="cardtext">
                        <h3 class="sectext" style="margin-bottom: 4%;">Get <span class="fw-bold">Electric</span>  or <span class="fw-bold">Fuel-Efficient</span> vehicles </h3>
                        <p class="sectext">While an Electric vehicle is the best option of the two, getting a vehicle that consumes less gasoline is also a decent option.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cardimage"><img src="assets/img/car.jpg" style="border-top-right-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;" height="300" width="400">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function opencs() {
        let remove = document.getElementById("textwrap");
            remove.classList.remove("remove");
            remove.classList.add("remove");
    };
</script>

</html>
```

hope this help ,
one addition css,
little changes in html
and additional js